# Fourier transform of scaled function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

Let us consider following example

$$x(at)\iff\dfrac1{|a|}X\left(j\left(\dfrac\omega a\right)\right).$$

one thing which i did not understand  is where  absolute value of $a$ came from? Ok if we have

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x(a*t)*e^{-j\omega*t}dt$$

then we may have denote  $y=a*t$ from which $t=\frac {y} {a}$ and also $dy=dt*a$ or $$dt=\frac {dy} {a}$$
so when we will put  all this thing we will get

$$\frac{1}{a}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x(y)*e^{-j\omega*\frac {y}{a}}dy$$  this should equal

$$\frac{1}{a}*X\left(j*\left(\frac{\omega}{a}\right)\right)$$  what about absolute value?thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have supposed that $a>0$.

You have to take cases for $a$.

In the case of $a<0$ the absolute value will appear.

$a<0:$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(a \cdot t) \cdot e^{-j \omega t}dt$$
$$y=a \cdot t \Rightarrow t=\frac{y}{a}$$
$$dy=adt$$
$$\text{ When } t \rightarrow -\infty  \Rightarrow y \rightarrow +\infty$$
$$\text{ When } t \rightarrow +\infty  \Rightarrow y \rightarrow -\infty$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(a \cdot t) \cdot e^{-j \omega t}dt=\frac{1}{a}\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} x(y) \cdot e^{-j \omega \frac{y}{a}} dy=-\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(y) \cdot e^{-j \frac{\omega}{a} y} dy=\frac{1}{-a}X(j(\frac{\omega}{a}))=\frac{1}{|a|}X(j(\frac{\omega}{a}))$$

Since $a<0$, $-a$ is the positive value of $a$, so it equal to $|a|$.

Comment: that means that  fourier transform must not be negative?

Comment: ok please if you have time

Comment: I edited my answer...

Comment: yes clearly understood eveything